# Windows 8.1 Create POST request

Tags: c#, windows, http-post, windows-8.1

I would like to create a POST request to connect my application to a server with windows 8.1 and C#.
I saw on the microsoft API that POST request must use differents library between w8 and w8.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761504.aspx
How can I create an IHTTPContent ? I don't understand how to cast a string to this.
Should I use `HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri,iHTTPContent)`

Answer (score 5):

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.ihttpcontent.aspx

There are many classes which implements IHttpContent (go to the Remarks part), you should take one depending on your needs, create it, add the content and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

If your content is a string (text, json, xml), you can pass in `new HttpStringContent(yourStringContent)`